# Wait for a function to finish, then move on to the rest of a Gulp task

Tags: javascript, json, callback, gulp, promise

I'm trying to build an FTP gulp task that relies on an ftp.json file that contains connection information. This file gets included in the .gitignore, so when a developer clones the repo, it doesn't exist. I run a check to see if they set up an ftp.json, and if one doesn't exist, it downloads a blank one.

The issue I'm running in to is that while it does download the file, it also throws an error, ending the task. I'd like to have something that says "wait for this function to finish, then move on to the rest of the task" to prevent the error from occurring. Here's my current FTP task:

```
// upload to FTP environment
gulp.task("ftp", function(callback) {
    // development FTP directory
    var ftpDirectory = dev;

    // production FTP directory (if --dist is passed)
    if (argv.dist) {
        ftpDirectory = dist;
    }

    // check if the FTP.json exists
    fs.exists("./ftp.json", function(exists) {
        // if it doesn't, download it
        if (!exists) {
            download("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/revxx14/a04f5ba7e00b267e71e2/raw/197fcf2478cc7ee77afaa4d200f908ccdccbc822/ftp.json")
                .pipe(gulp.dest("./"));
        }
    }); // should wait here, and only continue once the download completes.

    // read FTP credentials fromt ftp.json
    var host = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.host"),
        user = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.user"),
        pass = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.pass"),
        path = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.path");

    // read dist FTP credentials from ftp.json (if --dist is passed)
    if (argv.dist) {
        host = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.host"),
        user = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.user"),
        pass = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.pass"),
        path = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.path");
    }

    // reconfigure ftp.json if a field is empty or if --config is passed
    if (host === "" || user === "" || pass === "" || argv.config) {
        gulp.src("./ftp.json")
            .pipe(prompt.prompt([{
                // prompt for the hostname
                type: "input",
                name: "host",
                message: "host:",
                default: host,
            },
            {
                // prompt for the username
                type: "input",
                name: "user",
                message: "username:",
                default: user,
            },
            {
                // prompt for the password
                type: "password",
                name: "pass",
                message: "password:",
                default: pass,
            },
            {
                // prompt for the remote path
                type: "input",
                name: "path",
                message: "remote path:",
                default: path,
            }], function(res) {
                // open the ftp.json
                var file = json.read("./ftp.json");

                // set connection to dev
                var connection = "dev";

                // set connection to dist (if --dist is passed)
                if (argv.dist) {
                    connection = "dist";
                }

                // update the file contents
                file.set(connection + ".host", res.host);
                file.set(connection + ".user", res.user);
                file.set(connection + ".pass", res.pass);
                file.set(connection + ".path", res.path);

                // write the updated file contents
                file.writeSync();
            }));
    }

    // create the FTP connection
    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: host,
        user: user,
        pass: pass,
        path: path,
    })

    // upload the changed files
    return gulp.src(ftpDirectory + "/**/*")
        .pipe(conn.newer(path))
        .pipe(conn.dest(path));
})
```

I'm using `gulp-download` for the download functionality, if that matters. would be happy to move to something else if it meant I could get this working.

Comment: I would separe those different tasks into separate tasks and then, add them as dependencies chaining them together, the next task would only start after the dependency is complete [task dependency](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md)

Comment: Thanks, will look in to that.

Comment: Okay, I'm running in to a similar problem where my new task `ftp-init`, which just contains the downloaded, "finishes" before downloading is complete. Hmm.

Comment: This is what I meant [gulp deps](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps) I use a similar task to serve my app, first I lint, then inject css / js files to html then, start the app. I never tried in a situation like yours, yet, I think (I might be wrong) that the principle is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to @rmjoia, I figured out how to set up dependencies. Here's my final task set:

```
// initialize ftp.json
gulp.task("ftp-init", function(cb) {
    // check if the ftp.json exists
    fs.stat("./ftp.json", function (err, stats) {
        if (err != null) {
            // if it doesn't, create it
            fs.writeFile("./ftp.json", "{\"dev\": {\"host\": \"\",\"user\": \"\",\"pass\": \"\",\"path\": \"\"\},\"dist\": {\"host\": \"\",\"user\": \"\",\"pass\": \"\",\"path\": \"\"\}}", function (err) {
                cb(err);
            });
        } else {
            // otherwise return
            cb(err);
        }
    });
});

// configure FTP credentials in ftp.json, depends on ftp-init
gulp.task("ftp-config", ["ftp-init"], function(cb) {
    // read FTP credentials from ftp.json
    host = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.host"),
    user = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.user"),
    pass = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.pass"),
    path = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dev.path");

    // read dist FTP credentials from ftp.json (if --dist is passed)
    if (argv.dist) {
        host = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.host"),
        user = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.user"),
        pass = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.pass"),
        path = json.read("./ftp.json").get("dist.path");
    }

    if (host === "" || user === "" || pass === "" || argv.config) {
        // reconfigure ftp.json if a field is empty or if --config is passed
        gulp.src("./ftp.json")
            .pipe(prompt.prompt([{
                // prompt for the hostname
                type: "input",
                name: "host",
                message: "host:",
                default: host,
            },
            {
                // prompt for the username
                type: "input",
                name: "user",
                message: "username:",
                default: user,
            },
            {
                // prompt for the password
                type: "password",
                name: "pass",
                message: "password:",
                default: pass,
            },
            {
                // prompt for the remote path
                type: "input",
                name: "path",
                message: "remote path:",
                default: path,
            }], function(res) {
                // open the ftp.json
                var file = json.read("./ftp.json");

                // set connection to dev
                var connection = "dev";

                // set connection to dist (if --dist is passed)
                if (argv.dist) {
                    connection = "dist";
                }

                // update the file contents
                file.set(connection + ".host", res.host);
                file.set(connection + ".user", res.user);
                file.set(connection + ".pass", res.pass);
                file.set(connection + ".path", res.path);

                // write the updated file contents
                file.writeSync();

                cb(null);
            }));
    } else {
        // otherwise return
        cb(null);
    }
})

// upload to FTP environment
gulp.task("ftp-upload", ["ftp-config", "ftp-init"], function(cb) {
    // development FTP directory
    var ftpDirectory = dev;

    // production FTP directory (if --dist is passed)
    if (argv.dist) {
        ftpDirectory = dist;
    }

    // create the FTP connection
    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: host,
        user: user,
        pass: pass,
        path: path,
    })

    // upload the changed files
    return gulp.src(ftpDirectory + "/**/*")
        .pipe(conn.newer(path))
        .pipe(conn.dest(path));

    // return
    cb(null);
});

// combine FTP tasks
gulp.task("ftp", ["ftp-upload", "ftp-config", "ftp-init"]);
```

Seems kind of ridiculously complex, but it works, so I'm happy for now.